# How do I deny/prevent users opening links in my site in new tabs on their browser?

Tags: php, javascript, browser

There's a javascript generated link and I need to make sure the users can't open it either by not being able to right click and choose open in new tab, or by making that action do nothing at all.

Any ideas?

Edit:
I didn't raise up the question to ask whether or not it's right to do it, but to know if it's possible. If you can help me with an appropriate answer please do, otherwise don't give me suggestions to problems I don't need solved. Sorry for the attitude.

Comment: Don't.... don't do that.  You're creating a real usability mess.

Comment: The best you can do is frustrate and inconvenience them. If they want to, they'll find a way around it. More likely they'll just stop opening any of your pages altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done. Simple. Not possible

Answer (score 3):

> There's a javascript generated link and I need to make sure the users can't open it either by not being able to right click and choose open in new tab, or by making that action do nothing at all.

Can't be done. To be honest, I can't see a legitimate reason for anyone to want this either. The result of opening a page in a tab is no different from just opening the page. Anyway, there's no way to tell whether your site has been opened in one tab, or in different tabs.

Comment: ... or in a different browser... or in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

Your best solution might be to avoid using a link at all.  Instead, use a `<span>` or `<div>` (or similar) and bind a click event handler that redirects the page.

```
document.getElementById("mylinkdiv").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.location.href = "foo.html"
}
```

**In general this is bad**, because you don't want you site functionality to depend on JavaScript being enabled, *but* you've already said that the user needs JavaScript to see the link in the first place.

Comment: for a browsergame, you use exactly this technique, theres nothing bad about it if you know what you are doing :)

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by disabling right click on your page. Since "open link in new tab" is a browser specific feature you can't selectively disable that feature in right click menu.
Put this script in your web page to disable right click.

```
<script language=JavaScript>
     var message = "You cannot right Click on this page"; 
     function rtclickcheck(keyp){ if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" && keyp.which == 3)
     {
       alert(message); 
       return false;
     } 
     if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 && event.button == 2) 
     {
       alert(message);
       return false;
     }
 } 
   document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;
</script>
```

Comment: `navigator.appName == "Netscape"` sounds like that script comes from a time where people thought you could protect your "source" by disabling a right-mouse click. Also, hogging the document.onmousedown isn't very polite.

Comment: @Manish Kumar - this is not a solution for the OP. user still could use scroll wheel or shift+click or ctrl+click

Comment: If you're seriously going to disable right click, please at least limit your UI damage to the specific link in question.